# Remove default text after clicking in the TextBox in c#

Tags: c#, textbox, onclick

When you activate an application, a TextBox with text "[Hello]" will appear.

When you click on the TextBox in order to make input data, I want to remove the text automatically in c# code, how do I do it ?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtM" runat="server" Text="[Hello]"></asp:TextBox>
```

Can you please help me figure out the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, see this !

http://dotnetdrizzles.blogspot.it/2015/03/how-to-clear-textbox-value-when-user.html

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" 
  onclick="if (this.value == 'Enter Name') {this.value='' ;this.style.color = 'black'}" 
    onblur="if(this.value.length==0) { this.value='Enter Name';this.style.color = 'grey'}" 
        Width="275px" ForeColor="#999999">Enter Name</asp:TextBox>
```